# segment fault 11 when install ruby 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, secure-coding, rails-security

I need to install ruby 3.0.0 on my machine to upgrade my ROR application gems, I use RVM as version management but when I write RVM install 3.0.0 I have this error

> Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
>
> please read /Users/hadii/.rvm/log/1620191440_ruby-3.0.0/make.log
>
> There has been an error while running makes. Halting the installation.

when I tail make.log file I found this :

```
tail /Users/hadii/.rvm/log/1620191440_ruby-3.0.0/make.log
./revision.h unchanged
compiling version.c
linking miniruby
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
generating x86_64-darwin19-fake.rb
x86_64-darwin19-fake.rb updated
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
make: *** [exe/ruby] Segmentation fault: 11
make: *** Deleting file `exe/ruby'
++++++++++++ support:384 @__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

I google a lot and do a lot of things like uninstall RVM, ruby from my machine and reinstall it again, reconfigure RVM whit this command :

> RVM get head
>
> RVM get master

I even follow this [link](https://brettterpstra.com/2020/08/06/solving-rvm-and-openssl-issues-with-homebrew/) but nothings change, even I try to install a newer version of ruby-like 3.0.1 and even try this command

> RVM install "ruby-3.0.0"

but I couldn't install any new version of ruby, please help me

I work on my iMac that my os version is Catalina

ruby version which works now 2.7.1

Rails 5.2.5

rvm 1.29.12

UPDATE:

I try to install ruby manully and follow this [tutorials](https://github.com/ruby/ruby#how-to-compile-and-install) but get this error messages

```
BASERUBY = /Users/hadii/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = clang -fdeclspec
    LD = clang
    LDSHARED = clang -fdeclspec -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -std=gnu99  -pipe
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-pie -framework Security -framework Foundation
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    LC_ALL =
    LC_CTYPE =
    MFLAGS =
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
./revision.h unchanged
make: *** [exe/ruby] Segmentation fault: 11
make: *** Deleting file `exe/ruby'
```

Comment: does the following help: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5055

Comment: @jad thanks about yr comment but i still have same issues even with this link

Comment: `rvm get head ; rvm install 3.0.0 --with-gcc=clang` assuming you have clang installed?

Comment: I do what you said but this is my response about rvm get head:
scripts/snapshot: Can't unlink already-existing object
scripts/tools: Can't unlink already-existing object
scripts/upgrade: Can't unlink already-existing object
scripts/wrapper: Can't unlink already-existing object
scripts/zsh/: Can't restore time
scripts/zsh/Completion/: Can't restore time
scripts/zsh/Completion/_rvm: Could not remove symlink scripts/zsh/Completion/_rvm
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Could not extract RVM sources.
Could not update RVM, please report to https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues

Comment: and this is rsponse of 
❯ rvm install 3.0.0 --with-gcc=clang
ruby-3.0.0 - #removing src/ruby-3.0.0 - please wait
Checking requirements for osx.
We don't know how to ensure that selected compiler 'clang' exists.
Updating certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/hadii/.rvm/log/1620213626_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: and tails of error is:
x86_64-darwin19-fake.rb updated
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
make: *** [exe/ruby] Segmentation fault: 11
make: *** Deleting file `exe/ruby'
++++++++++++ support:384 @__rvm_make:0> return 2

Comment: some of these errors make me think that you may have run `sudo` on your `rvm` at some point. if you can bear it, it might be best to `mv .rvm .rvm.bak` in your home directory, then reinstalling rvm, without sudo

Comment: @jad sorry for my delay, i follow what u said spet by step even reinstall rvm but still have same problem, i really have no idea what happen but nothings change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after longtime googling and have a lot of issues that I explained before, I found this [link](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1505)
that explained these three command witch help to fix these issues.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```